# How to get large data from webservice partial?

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, jsf, jsf-2

I've application in JSF 2.0 (on Glassfish 3). Now I have to write a .NET WCF webservice that will be connected to database and will be used by this JSF app to fill DataTables.

DataTable will have pagination, but how to get (form web-service) only that rows, which will be displayed in single page. And will allow action such as sorting, deleting, editing rows etc...

Is there any bulit-in mechanism/library to supported that? I mean in WCF or JSF2 ?

Thanks for help,

Comment: IMO your web service should return 2 data: one with the total count of the rows to return, and the second value that contains the 30 (or the quantity of rows you need) to display the data. Based on the count result, you could set the number of pages to your `<h:dataTable>` (or another component with similar behavior) and add behavior on every page to get the results for that page.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a WSDL file (ask the web service owner/maintainer/admin for it). A WSDL file specifies by XML how the webservice is definied. A bit sane IDE like Eclipse can autogenerate a complete Java client application for it via *File > New > Other... > Web Services > Web Service Client*. You should then end up with an autogenerated web service client project which you just have to add as *Deployment Assembly* of your JSF project in order to access/use the autogenerated client classes.

[You can find here a concrete tutorial](http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html) which shows how to generate and use it in combination with a plain Java application project (instead of a JSF project).

As to partially retrieving the data, that depends on whether the web service supports that as per the WSDL. You can always issue an enhancement request at the maintainer of the web service so that they will add this to the web service (and then you should get an updated version of the WSDL and then re-generate the Java client application based on it).

Comment: Thanks, apparently I can't even consume web service properly, so I will get back here as soon as I resolve that issue